# Stiff equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

If I am looking at equilibrium points in stiff equations (ODE) How would I go about determining If a function is stiff?

Example functions:

$$y'=-10sin(y)$$

or

$$y'=t-y $$
I believe that the number has to be negative but not sure if that is always the case. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: There is no precise definition of a stiff differential equation. Essentially, if a few standard methods of solving the ODE fail, then you are justified in saying the equation is stiff.